# Changing dot net target framework from 4.0 to 4.5 is not changing the Runtime version of the dll referenced.

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, dll, frameworks

I have a .Net solution which has some 16 projects, now I have to migrate target framework from 4.0 to 4.5 and some of the projects in that solution are referenced by other projects in the solution as dlls.

My problem is even after changing the .Net framework version to 4.5 in project properties the runtime version is still showing 4.0 only and that is terminating my application.

Comment: There have been only two runtime versions in the past 9 years, v2.0.50727 and v4.0.30319.  Additional .NET versions released in this period just added extra assemblies.  Like 4.5 did.  So whatever your problem might be, it is **not** what you think.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant got your point, searching a bit more about it revealed that there is a difference between the runtime version (CLR version) and dll version. My problem was something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be making project references in VS instead of DLL references whenever possible. Your problem is just one of the benefits of Project References over Assembly References. The main difference is that by making a project reference VS will be smarter when resolving dependencies, for example, if you compile one project VS resolve all dependant projects (if in the same solution) and determine whether it needs to compile this dependant project or not, VS will even warn you if the reference is using a higher version of the .NET Framework. Notice, that you will still need to change the "Target Framework" for each project.

To add a project reference...

1. Right-click the project
2. Click on "Add reference..."
3. Select the "Projects" tab instead of the "Browse..." tab on the left-hand side panel to display the list of projects in the current solution

See screenshot below...

[image]

Sometimes you won't be able to make a Project Reference, in that case you will need to recompile your project (run a clean command if required) and then redeploy the DLL by overriding the dll reference